# How to close pop up window on automation using Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

here with this code, i'm trying to close the Alert window directly, without clicking anywhere inside the window.

```
public void Alert(string action) throws exception{
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
    //writing the code to dismiss the alert window
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.dismiss();
    driver.close();

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck? What error do you see?

Comment: try/catch the driver.close() call and include the exception in your post.  ( if no exception is shown there, try/catch the switchTo().alert() call and include that one.)  You should also check the handles against the parentWindowHandle... the order of the array is not guaranteed.

Comment: I got the exception as "No Such Alert present"    - this got after switching to popup window [ driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window ]

Comment: i could close the confirmation alert window by sending enter/space keys directly.  But i don't wanna use this method now,  i want to click on the cancel button of the alert window. is there any possibility?

Comment: The exception is telling you there is no alert.  Just remove the lines that deal with alert and close the window.

Comment: u mean, removing this part of the code '//writing the code to dismiss the alert window' and just keeping "driver.close()" under this "driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window"?

Comment: Yes I do.......assuming there's another tab/window being opened here.  It's not real clear why you're trying to do both things.